# Connecting to redis pod from another pod in the same cluster

Tags: kubernetes, redis

In my cluster I have a nodejs application pod and a redis pod, and I am trying to connect to redis from nodejs, but I am getting the following error:

`[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND redis at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)`

It is worth noting that in my nodejs app I am pointing at redis:6379 and if I change the pointer to localhost:6379, I will get a `ECONNREFUSED` error.

My redis deployment yaml looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  containers:
    - name: redis
      image: redis:5.0.4
      command:
        - redis-server
        - '/redis-master/redis.conf'
      env:
        - name: MASTER
          value: 'true'
      ports:
        - containerPort: 6379
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: '0.1'
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /redis-master-data
          name: data
        - mountPath: /redis-master
          name: config
  volumes:
    - name: data
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: config
      configMap:
        name: redis-config
        items:
          - key: redis-config
            path: redis.conf
```

Mu redis service yaml is the following:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-master
  labels:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
spec:
  ports:
    - name: redis
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
  selector:
    app: redis
    role: master
    tier: backend
```

And the service of my app looks like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: bff
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '8080'
  labels:
    app: bff
spec:
  ports:
    - name: external
      port: 80
      targetPort: web
      protocol: TCP
    - name: metrics
      port: 8080
      targetPort: metrics
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: bff
```

I have tried following other answers given to similar questions, but they do not seem to work in my case.

Comment: share output of kubectl describe svc redis-master. Also the application pod and redis pod are in same namespace?

Comment: Pods are running in the same namespace, will add the describe output in edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is your service `selector` definition doesn't match your pods's lables.

Quote from Kubernetes service document:

> The controller for the Service selector continuously scans for Pods that match its selector, and then POSTs any updates to an Endpoint object also named “my-service”.

See [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for full document.

In short, by following [this Kubernetes official example](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/guestbook), you should deploy the `deployment` "redis-master-deployment.yaml" instead of bare pod.

Comment: Now that I have made this change I am getting 172.20.173.232:6379 ECONNREFUSED

Comment: I took this from the official kubernetes documentation also: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/guestbook/redis-master-service.yaml

Comment: Here is the suggestions to diagnostic the issue: 1, exec into your redis pod, use netstat make sure the redis is running and listening on 0.0.0.0:6379. 2, exec into the app pod, install the `telnet` command line, try `telnet 172.20.173.232 6379` to check connection from app pod to service.

Comment: From the [official github example](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/guestbook), you need deploy the `deployment` redis-master-deployment.yaml instead of bare pod in your code (`kind: Pod`)

Comment: Ok, I will try that. thanks, will let you know in a minute.

Comment: Making that change for kind worked. Could you please update your answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Updated the answer. It is pleasure that your issue solved.